# White color is not white in Windows Picture Viewer

Tags: windows-7, display, colors, image-viewer, pictures

Recently bought new monitor. And connected it with HDMI. No new monitor extends my laptops in-built monitor. There is 1 problem with white color (all other colors are awesome)

This is how Windows 7 Picture viewer and Windows Live Photo Viewer shows picture. (As you see not only picture but background of viewer is another tone).

[image]

This is how Photoshop shows it
[image]

Both monitors are showing color like that. How to fix that problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Go into `Control Panel > Color Management`.
2. Disable the color profile for your monitor (or set it to sRGB).

Comment: Don't forget to restart windows

Comment: Main question here: What if I am using a calibrated icc profile so I specifically WANT Windows to use my color profile and it works perfectly all of the time for everything else. But the Windows Photo App on Win10 looks way way too red?

Comment: @dotNET Ninja You don't need to reboot Windows. Only press close in color management window and reopen photo viewer.

Answer (score 10):

It seems it is a [common](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/939395/en-us) - [problem](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942632/en-us). 
To fix this problem, you have to remove the incorrect color profile. To do this, follow these steps:

- Click `Start`, type `Color Management` in the Start Search box, and then
  press ENTER. In the Color Management dialog box, click to select the
  `Use my settings for this device` check box.
- In the `Profiles associated with this device` list, click the color
  profile that you want to remove, and then click Remove.
- Note If you receive a warning message, click Yes. Close the `Color
  Management` dialog box and then restart the computer to apply the
  setting.

**Update:**

- If there is no color profile present, then Click Add, and add `sRGB IEC61966-2.1` color profile and make it default. Then restart.

Comment: there is no profile in this list. List is empty. http://prntscr.com/5pegj

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Some directions here may help, https://optimwise.com/fix-windows-photo-viewer-yellow-tint-background/

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for something different but had to chime in since the chosen answer is very inaccurate.

Yes it fixes the problem the user is having because the problem was most likely to do with a corrupt monitor profile.

But if you happen to be someone who photoshops your photos then you'll want the most accurate representation of colour and the only way to do that is with custom ICC profiles.

Assuming he deletes the corrupt profiles, everything will revert to looking the same but that means that he is also without a custom profile.

I don't think I've managed to explain it as well as some of the other people here..

http://www.lightroomforums.net/showthread.php?14070-How-to-assign-an-sRGB-ICC-Profile-to-your-monitor-(Windows)

http://www.dpbestflow.org/color/color-space-and-color-profiles#space

TL;DR: You want to delete the profile if it is corrupted but no you shouldn't just leave it at that.

Comment: It's not about "corrupted". Sometimes you have software (or user, thinking to be "smart") installing 'super-duper' profiles.. Only to mess up gamma or anything else. And sometimes you don't notice that months after the fact. BTW, it looks like there may also be [bugs in windows](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/dacd4cf2-56cb-4089-8f2d-834420754a91/windows-photo-viewer-and-icc-profiles)